# Adding Ad Mediation networks to AdMob when old App versions are missing the libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

If I add more Ad Mediation networks to my iOS App on AdMob, will the old version of the App crash because it doesn't have the proper SDK libraries to serve the ad? Should I instead be making ANOTHER ad unit and using that from now on? Or is it safe to continue with the same one and the App gracefully detect that the SDKs are not there and ignore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't crash. It will ignore ad networks for which the libraries do not exist on the client.